# avoid callback with await cypress doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have alias on my fixture stub, so this is working for me:

```
describe("some page", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept("/users", {
      fixture: users.json,
    });
    cy.visit("/somewhere");
  });

  it("show something", () => {
    cy.wait("@firstApiCall").then(() => {
      cy.wait("@2ndApiCall").then(() => {
        cy.get("test:something").should("exist");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

but this won't work?

```
it("show something", () => {
  await cy.wait("@firstApiCall");
  await cy.wait("@firstApiCall");

  cy.get("test:something").should("exist");
});
```

Also, how can I avoid repeating `cy.wait(apiCall)` in each `it` block?

Answer (score 0):

It probably fails with:

```
Unexpected reserved word 'await'.
```

and that's because `await` keyword could be used only in `async` functions, your callback function is not async.

You might write:

```js
it("show something", async () => {
  await cy.wait("@firstApiCall");
  await cy.wait("@firstApiCall");

  cy.get("test:something").should("exist");
});
```

But I wonder why do you want to do it? Cypress does a good job running the commands in the order in which they are written (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Commands-Run-Serially).

I also doubt your example actually works:

```js
describe("some page", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept("/users", {
      fixture: users.json,
    });
    cy.visit("/somewhere");
  });

  it("show something", () => {
    cy.wait("@firstApiCall").then(() => {
      cy.wait("@2ndApiCall").then(() => {
        cy.get("test:something").should("exist");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

You don't alias `firstApiCall` and `2ndApiCall`, so Cypress doesn't know what to wait for.